# ko.utils.arrayMap, but only return part of the array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using some of the Knockout utility functions described brilliantly here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

I want to do an arrayMap to select certain properties based on a condition, e.g.

```
return ko.utils.arrayMap(myObservableArray(), function (item) {
    return item.Label;
});
```

Say for example this produces the following output:

```
[null, "", "SomeLabel", null, "SomeOtherLabel"]
```

I want to select the properties based on a condition, so I try:

```
return ko.utils.arrayMap(myObservableArray(), function (item) {
    if (item.Label && item.Label !== "") {
        return item.Label;
    }
});
```

However then you end up with an array like:

```
[undefined, undefined, "SomeLabel", undefined, "SomeOtherLabel"]
```

I've also tried this:

```
return ko.utils.arrayMap(myObservableArray(), function (item) {
    return (item.Label && item.Label !== "") ? item.Label : false;
});
```

but you get:

```
[false, false, "SomeLabel", false, "SomeOtherLabel"]
```

So I am then having to do:

```
var itemsWithLabels = ko.utils.arrayFilter(myObservableArray(), function (item) {
    return (item.Label && item.Label !== "");
});
return ko.utils.arrayMap(itemsWithLabels, function (item) {
    return item.Label;
});
```

Which will give me:

```
["SomeLabel", "SomeOtherLabel"]
```

Is there a more efficient way of accomplishing this, in one shot, using ko.utils or similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you noticed, with ko.utils.arrayMap it is expected your callback returns something. SO this is a 'dumb function' that always appends the return value of the callback to the array. Returning undefined, null or false does not omit the value from the resulting array.

arrayFilter allows for no way to modify the filtered item: the original item will be pushed to the result array.

So in short, this cannot be done more efficiently with the ko.utils.array* functions. You could combine them and make the code a bit more verbose, perhaps even put them in a computed:

```
var itemsWithLabels = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayMap(ko.utils.arrayFilter(myObservableArray(), function (item) {
        return item.Label && item.Label.length;
    }), function (filteredItem) {
        return filteredItem.Label;
    });
});
```

But this is the best you can do. I chose to first apply the filter, and afterwards do the mapping, because it seems to me the mapping would be more expensive than the filtering. But that's just a hunch.

Maybe a library such as Underscore provides methods to do this directly.

It's also fairly easy to write such a method yourself (and possible put it in ko.utils if you wish)

```
    ko.utils.arrayMapFilter = function (array, mapping) {
        array = array || [];
        var result = [], mapResult;
        for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++) {
            mapResult = mapping(array[i]);
            if (mapResult) {
                result.push(mapResult);
            }
        }
        return result;
    },
```

your mapping callback can now return falsy values such as 0, "", false, null or undefined, and they won't end up in the array.

If you want to permit a few of the above values anyway (such as 0 or ""), then just change the line:

```
if (mapResult)
```

to something more strict, like:

```
if (mapResult !== undefined && mapResult !== null)
```

Comment: Your `for` loop was a classic illustration of the perils of not enclosing the body of a control statement in a block; the indentation showed the nesting you wanted, not the nesting you got.

Comment: I totally agree braces are best practise. Always use them :) in this case I started out with a copy of Knockout's functions and edited it on SO. Hence the missing braces.

Answer (score 1):

Hans's second method can be shortened a little to

```
ko.utils.arrayMapFilter = function (array, mapping) {
    var result = [], mapResult;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(ko.unwrap(array || []), function (item) {
        mapResult = mapping(item);
        if (mapResult) {
            result.push(mapResult);
        }
    });
    return result;
};
```

which will work on either a plain array or an `observableArray` (returning a plain array in both cases). <s>It's worth timing it since some JS engines' internal implementations of `foreach` (which `ko.utils.arrayForEach` uses if available) are alleged to be slower than using a `for` loop on the array, though the difference is likely to be small.</s>

Comment: Actually, ko.utils.arrayForEach does not use native foreach:
`arrayForEach: function (array, action) {
            for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++)
                action(array[i]);
        },`, which is exactly what you'll find in my answer :)

Comment: Ah, I "misfocused"; the implementation of `arrayIndexOf` uses the native method if possible and it comes right after the code for `arrayForEach`.